# Trigger SQL Server DB update from Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to transfer data from Client's Oracle to my Sql Server db and keep that data up to date in the SQL Server DB. The clients Oracle DB is event driven ie CRUD on specific rows, not full data table refreshes.

If i simply set up a SQL Server Schedule task it will be out of date nearly all of the time.

Is it possible to have my SQL DB monitor my clients Oracle DB for updates to a specific set of tables?

I only want to update my DB with every event, not do a full refresh whenever anything small changes in Oracle DB tables

Any ideas? I usually i use SSIS to do this but not sure it can help here.

Comment: Why not simply set up a linked server and query your client's db for whatever you need?

Comment: Because theyre db has event driven tables and i need to act when an event occurs, ie they're table updates then i should react.

Answer (score 0):

My first comment is that the databases do not know what you think is "small".

But, it sounds like you want transactional replication between heterogeneous servers.  It turns out that SQL Server seems to support this (I hadn't known).  And specifically for your use-case:  From Oracle to SQL Server.

The place to get started is the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151149(v=sql.105).aspx).

Note:  I have not used this feature of SQL Server so I do not know how well it works in practice.